# error when flutter app loads jitsi meet in IOS WKWebviews

Tags: flutter, jitsi, jitsi-meet

flutter app, loads jitsi meet in iOS WKWebview, screen shows "It looks like you're using a browser we don't fully support". i got a solution, will include it as an answer. not sure if my solution works for all iOS devices, are just a group.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, adding the following solved the issue:

```
userAgent:
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.2 Safari/605.1.15",
```

got the value for userAgent by loading following url on my ios device:

```
whatsmyua.info
```